# What does "at" mean in distributed system?

Tags: system, distributed-system

at means what in distributed system?
tcc means try confirm cancel
distributed system module acid, basic,soga,I know acid is database`s concept,and I meet at module,I can not know it,any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solely based on the topic being distributed systems, AT might stand for [**Atomic Transactions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), although its hard to tell from the information you provided.